# How to fetch the car speed in unity car game

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have started the car game and developed AI, car control script.

Now I want to know the speed of the car.

I have used the below code.

```
BackLeftWheel.wheelTorque = EngineTorque / GearRatio * 4;
```

The car is going smoothly, but I want to know its exact speed.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the car you are using, but as long as your script has access  to the transform of your car, you can always check the last position based on time, and update the speed this way...

```c#
Vector3 prevpos;

void Update()  
{  
    Vector3 distance_traveled = transform.position - prevpos;

    prevpos = transform.position

    Vector3 distancepertime = distance_traveled / time.deltaTime;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the car has a rigidbody, you can just do rigidbody.velocity.magnitude to get the speed.  [See here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html)

some notes though: don't call GetComponent in Update, call it in Start and store the result.
also: calculating magnitude requires a square root operation.  if possible this should be avoided in Update (although, having a few in the project probably won't matter too much)